# Website traffic divert and remove the information in website

Tags: routing, hosting, website

We hosted a website through the help of an private company(PC).  Our information is available in the website.  We terminated the services of the PC for certain reasons.  The login and password of the site is with the PC.  Due to termination the PC is refusing to give the site control to us.  Our customers are still contacting the site held by the PC. We now have created a new site with the same information.  Could you please let me know

(i) whether we can ask the registrar who has registered the new site for us to divert the traffic so that our customers can approach our site and not the site held by the PC? is it legally permissible.

(ii) the site held by PC has our information. Could we ask the registrar to remove our information since we do not want the PC to retain our information

Thanking you in anticipation

krish

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about b2b affairs, business contracts, Intellectual Property, or legalities.  While your question is asking about how to workaround these issues, it wouldn't be smart for an expert here to give you advice that could potentially harm either company.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the contract you have with the PC and who is registered to change the DNS (registrar).

1. It depends on whether you or the PC has the "contract" with the
   registrar. The registrar can change the DNS to point to whatever
   server "they" want.
2. The registrar has nothing to do with the information held by the server at the PC.

You need to get legal advice from someone who can read your contract and talk to the people involved.